# Detect when Firebase sign in has finished or canceled in this scenario

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-signin, detect

I learn ReactJs and now I must have Firebase signin. I have a design question on how to detect when Firebase `linkWithPopup` finish. User press `Button` and my anonymous user Firebase UID will be turned into a Google credential one.

The `linkWithPopup` pops up and user select one Google account to use.

I must detect when this process finish or aborted.

Here is my code:

This method get's called when user click Button for Google signin:

```
onSocialLoginLink = provider => {
    const { firebase, changeUserRole } = this.props;
    firebase.auth.currentUser
        .linkWithPopup(firebase[provider])
        // .linkWithRedirect(this.props.firebase[provider])
        .then(changeUserRole())
        .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
};
```

The problem I encounter is that `changeUserRole()` gets called before `linkWithPopup` returns since `linkWithPopup` of course run asynchronous. This means that my user get this new roll from `changeUserRole()` even if User select to abort signin.

I must detect when this process finish or aborted.

What would be a recommended best way to do this?
My ide is that if I can detect maybe when signin window looses focus and regain focus I could look at if Firebase user have changed provider to Google or is still anonymous user? Is this doable?

[image]

This is the `Component` that handle signin:

```
/* eslint-disable max-classes-per-file */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization } from '../../session';
import { withFirebase } from '../../firebase';
import { SIGN_IN_METHODS } from '../../constants/signinmethods';
import * as ROLES from '../../constants/roles';
import '../../styles/link-account.scss';
import { changeToUserRole } from '../../redux/userData/user.actions';

class LoginManagementBase extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            activeSignInMethods: [],
            anonymousSignIn: null,
            error: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchSignInMethods();
    }

    fetchSignInMethods = () => {
        const { firebase, authUser } = this.props;
        const email = authUser.email === null ? 'none@guest.ac' : authUser.email;
        firebase.auth
            .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)
            .then(activeSignInMethods =>
                this.setState({
                    activeSignInMethods,
                    anonymousSignIn: activeSignInMethods.length === 0,
                    error: null,
                }),
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
    };

    onSocialLoginLink = provider => {
        const { firebase, changeUserRole } = this.props;
        firebase.auth.currentUser
            .linkWithPopup(firebase[provider])
            // .linkWithRedirect(this.props.firebase[provider])
            .then(changeUserRole())
            .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
    };

    onDefaultLoginLink = password => {
        const { firebase, authUser } = this.props;
        const credential = firebase.emailAuthProvider.credential(authUser.email, password);

        firebase.auth.currentUser
            .linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
            .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
    };

    onUnlink = providerId => {
        const { firebase } = this.props;
        firebase.auth.currentUser
            .unlink(providerId)
            .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
    };

    render() {
        const { activeSignInMethods, error } = this.state;
        const { saveRolesErr, isSavingRole } = this.props;
        // if (isSavingRole) return null;
        return (
            <div className="provideToggler">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <h1>
                    You are signed in Anonymously!
                    <br />
                    Changes you do is only saved in this browser.
                    <br /> If you want to access your progress anywhere please sign in below!
                </h1>
                &nbsp;
                <ul>
                    {SIGN_IN_METHODS.map(signInMethod => {
                        const onlyOneLeft = activeSignInMethods.length === 1;
                        const isEnabled = activeSignInMethods.includes(signInMethod.id);
                        return (
                            <li key={signInMethod.id}>
                                {signInMethod.id === 'password' ? (
                                    <DefaultLoginToggle
                                        // accountEmail={this.props.authUser.email}
                                        onlyOneLeft={onlyOneLeft}
                                        isEnabled={isEnabled}
                                        signInMethod={signInMethod}
                                        onLink={this.onDefaultLoginLink}
                                        onUnlink={this.onUnlink}
                                    />
                                ) : (
                                    <SocialLoginToggle
                                        onlyOneLeft={onlyOneLeft}
                                        isEnabled={isEnabled}
                                        signInMethod={signInMethod}
                                        onLink={this.onSocialLoginLink}
                                        onUnlink={this.onUnlink}
                                    />
                                )}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
                <h1 style={{ color: 'red' }}>
                    {error && error.message}
                    {saveRolesErr && saveRolesErr.message}
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const SocialLoginToggle = ({ onlyOneLeft, isEnabled, signInMethod, onLink, onUnlink }) =>
    isEnabled ? (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onUnlink(signInMethod.id)} disabled={onlyOneLeft}>
            Unlink <i className={signInMethod.icon} aria-hidden="true" /> {signInMethod.name} sign in
        </button>
    ) : (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => onLink(signInMethod.provider)}>
            Link <i className={signInMethod.icon} aria-hidden="true" /> {signInMethod.name} sign in
        </button>
    );

// TODO This is not in use but might use it later
class DefaultLoginToggle extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { passwordOne: '', passwordTwo: '' };
    }

    onSubmit = event => {
        const { passwordOne } = this.state;
        const { onLink } = this.props;
        event.preventDefault();
        onLink(passwordOne);
        this.setState({ passwordOne: '', passwordTwo: '' });
    };

    onChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
        const { signInMethod } = this.props;
        const { passwordOne, passwordTwo } = this.state;
        const isInvalid = passwordOne !== passwordTwo || passwordOne === '';
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                Link <i className={signInMethod.icon} aria-hidden="true" /> {signInMethod.name} sign in
                <input
                    name="passwordOne"
                    value={passwordOne}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password for email sign in"
                />
                <input
                    name="passwordTwo"
                    value={passwordTwo}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Confirm New Password"
                />
                <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit">
                    Save password for email sign in
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    changeUserRole: () => dispatch(changeToUserRole()),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isSavingRole: state.user.isSavingRoles,
        saveRolesErr: state.user.saveRolesErrMsg,
    };
};

const enhance = compose(withFirebase, connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps));
const LoginManagement = enhance(LoginManagementBase);
const LinkAccounts = () => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (
            <div>
                <LoginManagement authUser={authUser} />
            </div>
        )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => authUser && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON);
export default withAuthorization(condition)(LinkAccounts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that's the problem you can add a condition to check than change the role

````
    const { firebase, changeUserRole } = this.props;
    firebase.auth.currentUser
        .linkWithPopup(firebase[provider])
        .then(res=>{
              if(res.credential){changeUserRole()}
         })
        .then(this.fetchSignInMethods)
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));
};```
````